# ORA-01654: unable to extend index by 8192 with enough free space

Tags: database-design, disk-space, tablespaces

I'm working in Oracle 19c DB. Block size is 8k.
I'm trying to insert new data in my table. I have enough free space (according to dba_free_space more than 2 GB).
But I've got ORA-01654: unable to extend index by 8192.
The question is why I need **8192*8k=64 MB** free space if **NEXT_EXTENT = 1048576 = 1MB**? And how to reuse my free space?

I've checked that i need free extents 64 MB or above, byt I have only 1-3 MB extents:

select count(*) as extents_qnt
from dba_free_space
where tablespace_name = 'MY_TABLESPACE'
and bytes/1024/1024 >= 64 -- 64 MB

```
EXTENTS_QNT
-------
0
```

select count(*) as extents_qnt
from dba_free_space
where tablespace_name = 'MY_TABLESPACE'
and bytes/1024/1024 BETWEEN 1 AND 3

```
EXTENTS_QNT
-------
1642
```

I've got an error because of the lack of large enough free extents.
But I still don't understand why I need 64 MB (not 1 MB).

Comment: You might not have uniform allocation. You want locally managed tablespaces with uniform allocation.  CREATE TABLESPACE testts
DATAFILE 'testts.dbf' SIZE 50M
EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL UNIFORM SIZE 1M;

Answer (score 0):

Oracle databases are split up into Tablespaces, each of which has its *own* size limit.
Looking at free space across the *whole* database is of questionable value.

It's also possible that you *have*, actually, run out of disk space but your Data Files(s) and/or Tablespaces are blissfully unaware of it.
For this reason, it's Good Practice to "pre-fill" [SMALLFILE] Data Files to their maximum size (32GB) *instead* of allowing them to "grow" automatically (AUTOEXTEND).  That way, Oracle Database has a complete picture of what's *really* available to it.

Comment: I don't look at free space across the whole database, but only 
**tablespace_name = 'MY_TABLESPACE'**
I'm more curious about why I need 64 MB instead of 1 MB to extent

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify `NEXT_EXTENT` size for a table:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name STORAGE (NEXT next_extent_size);
```

To modify the `NEXT_EXTENT` size for an index, use the following syntax:

```
ALTER INDEX index_name STORAGE (NEXT next_extent_size);
```

THIS IS AN EXAMPLE:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table STORAGE (NEXT 10M);
```

Hope this helps.

//Edit

You can also use the `autoextend` clause.

```
ALTER TABLESPACE tablespace_name AUTOEXTEND ON [NEXT next_extent_size] [MAXSIZE maximum_size];
```

EXAMPLE

```
ALTER TABLESPACE my_tablespace AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 10M MAXSIZE 1G;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer
I don't want to modify NEXT_EXTENT. I have default value 1MB, but for some reason it needs 64 MB to extent.